# How to check for list in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to read a file and process using LINQ.

I have a exclude list where if i encounter certain words in the file, i should omit that line

my code is

```
string sCodeFile = @"C:\temp\allcode.lst";
List<string> sIgnoreList = new List<string>() { "foo.c", "foo1.c" };
var wordsPerLine = from line in File.ReadAllLines(sCodeFile)
                   let items = line.Split('\n')
                   where !line.Contains(sIgnoreList.ToString())
                   select line;

foreach (var item in wordsPerLine)
{  
 console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

My LST file looks like below

```
\voodoo\foo.c
\voodoo\voodoo.h
\voodoo\std.c
\voodoo\foo1.h
```

in the end i want only

```
\voodoo\voodoo.h
\voodoo\std.c
```

How can i process the ignored list in contains? with my above code i dont get the desired output for sure

can any one help?

regards,
Karthik

Comment: you mention LINQ SQL, but this appears to be LINQ-to-Objects... is there any SQL here? or is that just a typo? (hint: it radically affects the answer)

Comment: Sorry Typo. My bad. I am trying to read the file contents using LINQ with some conditions

Comment: ALso: `line.Split('\n')` - a line rarely contains `\n`, else it isn't a line - should this be something involving slashes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Revised** my answer. The bug is that you're doing a `ToString` on the ignore list, which certainly will not work. You must check each item in the list, which can be done using something like this:

```
where !sIgnoreList.Any(ignore => line.Contains(ignore))
```

A curiosity: since the above lambda is just passing a value into a method that only take the value as a parameter, you can write this even more compact as a method group like this:

```
where !sIgnoreList.Any(line.Contains)
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo. But i sill dont get my desired result with this apporoack

Comment: @Karthik, see my revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
        string sCodeFile = @"C:\temp\allcode.lst";
        List<string> sIgnoreList = new List<string>() { "foo.c", "foo1.c" };

        var wordsPerLine = File.ReadAllLines(sCodeFile).Where(n =>
        {
            foreach (var ign in sIgnoreList)
            {
                if (n.IndexOf(ign) != -1)
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
```

It passes the current element (`n`) to a lambda function, which checks it against every element of the `sIgnoreList`. Returning `false` means the element is ignored, `true` means it's returned.

Comment: Maybe because you're looking for `foo.c` instead of `\voodoo\foo.c` ?

Comment: Yes i want to remove all the lines which contains foo.c . OK if i give full path it works. But I cannot provide full path due to my requirements

Comment: Please use Linq instead of `foreach`, my eyes hurt! :)

Comment: @Peter, please provide a suggestion how :)

Comment: Sure: `Where(n => !sIgnoreList.Any(ign => n.IndexOf(ign) != -1))`

Comment: Thank you! I've heard of `Any` but had no idea how to use it :)

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
where !sIgnoreList.Contains(line)
```

You need to compare ***each single line*** and check that it doesn't exist in the ignore list.

That's why the Vladislav's answer did not work.

Comment: Only if i provide full path this works which is not possible in my case as i have More than 2000 lines in my LST file

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working solution:

```
        var result = from line in File.ReadAllLines(codeFile)
                     where !ignoreList.Any(line.Contains)
                     select line;
```

The problem was you didn't want to check for the whole path and messed up words/lines part a bit.